# How to create an empty object with child classes that have __init__ method?

Tags: python, object

I have a class `C` which I am using to group together many other classes. When I create the instance `self.A` which is an empty object with child `Base`, there is no error because the `class Base` does not have an `__init__` method requesting inputs. However, I run into issues when creating the empty instance `self.B` because the `class B` is trying to `__init__` and is requesting arguments.

Here's the code:

```
class Base:
    def print(self):
        print('Print useful information about the collection of classes.')


class A(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.print()


class B(Base):
    def __init__(self, input_1: float, input_2: float):
        self.method(input_1, input_2)

    def method(self, input_1: float, input_2: float):
        print('input 1 {} and input 2 {}'.format(input_1, input_2))


class C(B, Base):
    def __init__(self, input_master: list):
        # create an instance for the C class
        self.A = type('', (Base,), {})()
        A.__init__(self.A)
        
        self.B = type('', (B, Base), {})()      # ERROR: the child B is trying to initialize
        B.__init__(self.B, input_master[0], input_master[1])


def main():
    C([1, 2])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there any way to create an empty object which is a parent to a child class containing and initialization function and requesting arguments?

Thank you for your time, please let me know if a more detailed description is necessary to adequately explain the issue.

Comment: The problem is that `__init__` *requires* those arguments, and you declined to supply them.  You have coded a direct contradiction in your object interface.  If you want to allow an empty object, then make the arguments optional.

Comment: So why can I  define `class C(B, Base)` without it giving me the same error message? `Class C` does not automatically call `Class B`'s `__init__` method. Why can't I define an "empty" object which has the same functionality as `Class C`?

Comment: This is really strange, why is `C` inheriting from `Base` *again*?

Comment: `self.A = type('', (Base,), {})()` why on earth are you doing this? Why not just `self.A = Base()`?  or `self.A = A()` There are major red flags with a lot of what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me your confusion stems from a misunderstanding of `__init__` and your use of `type`. With `type` you can dynamically create new classes, but here you want to simply use previously defined classes. Whenever you indeed initialize such a class, your provided arguments are passed to the `__init__` function, where you can do whatever you want with them.

I cleaned up your code and added comments to clarify the flow of things:

```py
# Create a blueprint for Base
class Base:
    def print_something(self):
        print('Something.')


# Create a blueprint for A
class A(Base):
    # Do some initialization whenever an instance of A is created.
    def __init__(self):
        print('Initializing A without any args')
        # Do some initialization
        self.answer = 42


# Create a blueprint for B
class B(Base):
    # An __init__ method with arguments
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        print(f'Initializing B with args: {foo}, {bar}')
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar


# Create a blueprint for C
class C(B, Base):
    # Do some initialization whenever an instance of C is created.
    def __init__(self, x):
        # Create an instance of A and store it as an attribute of the instance
        # of C that we are initializing here.
        self.a = A()
        # Do the same for B, but provide init arguments.
        self.b = B(x[0], x[1])


def main():
    # Create an instance of C
    c = C([1, 2])

    # Print some attributes to clarify the hierarchy
    print(c.a.answer)
    print(c.b.foo)
    print(c.b.bar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```